# complex vector fields - hard d vs. soft d?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, complex-geometry

I believe this is a computation I have done before, but now I can't write the symbols to convince myself:

What is the connection between the "hard" complex differential operator d/dz and the "soft" $\partial/\partial z$?

How does this make vector fields f(z)d/dz and f(z)$\partial/\partial z$ different?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: No difference. Thinking of $\mathbb C$ as a $1$-dimensional complex manifold, $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$ give a basis for the complexified tangent space, with \begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} &= \frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \quad\text{and} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z} &= \frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\,.\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is in their connotations.  When you write $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d z}$, I interpret you as meaning that you are working entirely and consistently only with holomorphic (or meromorphic, or analytic, ...) functions, so that you really can treat your domain $\mathbb C$ as one-dimensional.  When you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, I interpret you as allowing functions that have an antiholomorphic part, so that the other partial derivative $\frac\partial{\partial\bar z}$ may also act nontrivially.